# Abrir janela de pré visualização de impressão por javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Gostaria de saber como abrir essa janela de pré visualização de impressão do IE por javascript, eu preciso de um botão que abra essa janela, sem que eu precise ir até ela pelas configurações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `print` do objeto `window`.

```
window.print()
```

Se desejar vincular ao clique de um botão ficaria assim:

```
<input type="button" name="imprimir" value="Imprimir" onclick="window.print();">
```

Comment: Eu usei, mas ai ele já abre a janela para impressão, eu queria abrir essa de pre visualização antes, se for possível.

Comment: Teria um link de exemplo?

Comment: Não, só indo mesmo pelo click do botão direito no IE, ai tem lá a opção de pre visualizar. Mas pelo que pesquisei aqui parece que não tem como.
Mas muito obrigada!

Comment: Nos outros navegadores como chrome por exemplo essa função abre a tela de impressão, porém o arquivo abre ao lado pra pré visualizar, não sei como outros navegadores se comportam